# How to calculate branch lengths in an skeleton image using Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, mathematical-morphology

I am new to Matlab. I am doing image processing on a skeleton image. I am detecting branchpoints and endpoints using `bworph` function in Matlab. Now I want to calculate length of each branch in skeleton image. What are different options in Matlab and how to calculate length of image?

Following is the code I have used to find branchpoints and endpoints. Now I want to go to each branch in the image and determine length of it.

```
mn=bwmorph(y,'branchpoints');
[row column] = find(mn);
branchPts    = [row column];
endImg    = bwmorph(y, 'endpoints');
[row column] = find(endImg);
endPts       = [row column];
figure;imshow(y);
hold on ; 
plot(branchPts(:,2),branchPts(:,1),'rx');
hold on; plot(endPts(:,2),endPts(:,1),'*');
```

Comment: Check out this blog: http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/ it is very informative and I believe it covered a similar problem a few months/years ago

Answer (score 3):

If you take out the branch points - the branches become distinct connected components. They you can apply [`regionprops`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html) to get the desired properties

```
branches = y & ~mn; % set branch points to zero
branchesLabeled = bwlabel( branches, 4 ); % label connected components
sts = regionprops( branchesLabeled, 'Area', 'Perimeter' ); % extract properties
```